# Love2D on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, lua, 2d

Is there any porting of Love2D http://love2d.org/ game engine to iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Since 0.10

Yes! You can find the iOS download (`love-[version]-ios-source.zip`) on the [Bitbucket download page](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/downloads). It includes documentation on how to use it.

## Before 0.10

Unfortunately, not yet. The reason might be that Apple only allow static libraries on the iPhone.

Source: http://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2023&p=20788&hilit=iphone#p20788

Answer (score 4):

Bill Meltsner has started work on an iPhone port.
Check it out, it current;y only works in the simulator, but he seems to be progressing fairly well:
https://bitbucket.org/bmelts/love-iphone/overview

Answer (score 0):

There is now! Have a look at the Love2D Forum post right [here](http://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=76985)

It is stable and running, requirement is at least Xcode 4.3, working on iPhone, iPad, Simulator as well as real device.

Have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

The closest alternative would be the [Moai framework](http://getmoai.com/wiki/index.php?title=Moai_SDK_Basics_Part_One). It's a free, open source, Lua-based game engine/library, like LÖVE, but in addition to running on Windows, Mac and Linux, it runs on iOS and Android (and apparently the Chrome browser, too; no clue how that works, haven't tried it yet).

The API is a bit lower level than LÖVE, but from what I've seen so far it seems to be exceptionally well engineered and is super fast. [Wolf Toss](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wolf-toss/id461992615?mt=8) (also available on Android) was written with it.